# How do I use Objective-c to upload/download a file on the internet?

Tags: mysql, objective-c

This is for an iphone app.  The file uploaded/downloaded on the internet would be a basic leaderboard with a username or id or some sort, and three separate highscores for three modes within one game.

Further -  I would like to know if this can be achieved for free? For example could I upload an xml file or a plist file to a site like mediafire and still be able to upload there using objective-c?  With mediafire, for example, I already got the download working using the NSArray method initWithContentsOfURL:.  So far I have been unsuccessful in uploading to mediafire (Maybe using something with the NSURL password and host methods?).  Is there a way to do this on mediafire? or would it require another way of doing this?

I don't really wish to use Apple's Game-center. Do you think MySQL is required?

Comment: What's wrong with Game Center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously doubt MediaFire will offer an easy to use upload API (or an easy to use download API for that matter). Also, what happens when more than one user updates their high score at the same time?

I don't think MySQL is required, however you have moved beyond simple push/pull of a file, especially since the file has global state. This is what GameCenter and OpenFeint have tried to solve for you already, and if you don't have at least a shared hosting account with server side scripting capability you won't be able to solve this issue in an acceptable fashion.